# How to take the most similar rand generated string to a master string, mutate the random string through generations to achieve the original string?

Tags: python, loops, optimization, random, probability

i have generated N random sequences of length L in the letters A, C, G, T(e.g N= 10, L= 21) and created a function that calculates the distance between two 21 letter words,

[image]

as you can see, the output of this consists of the master genome and the mutations of said genome and how different the mutated genomes are from the original genome(how many characters are similar).

The issue is, i would like to be able to select the random sequence that has minimum distance to the 21-letter master sequence GATACCAATTACCAGATACCA. An alternative perspective of the same thing is to find the random sequence with the maximal overlap with the master sequence. This is a measure of fitness for these random sequences, and you select the random sequence with the highest fitness. Write a function that measures this overlap/fitness between a random 21-letter sequence and the master sequence.

After this initial step, create 10 offspring copies of that maximum fitness sequence, but evolve them by having a certain probability (e.g. 1/100) for each of the 21 letters to be randomly turned into a random letter of the alphabet (a mutation).

At each generation step, select from the 10 offspring the one with the highest fitness, and use that to evolve again in the next generation.

i would like to then be able to be able to repeat this process for a number of G generations, until the original master genome has been achieved through evolution- and how many generations it took- It should look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
master = list('AATTATGTACCGGGAGCTCCG')
mutation = list('GTATCACGATGTCATCATCAA')
nucleotides = ("A", "C", "G", "T")

def hamming_distance(mutation, x = 0):
    list = []
    if mutation != master:
        for i, nuc in enumerate(mutation):
            if nuc != master[i]:
                list.append(i)
        print(f'Mutated: {"".join(mutation)}, {len(mutation) - len(list)}, {x}')
        for num in list:
            y = random.choice(nucleotides)
            mutation[num] = y
        x += 1
        hamming_distance(mutation, x = x)
    elif mutation == master:
        print(f'Mutated: {"".join(mutation)}, {len(mutation) - len(list)}, {x}')
        print("Master sequence has been achieved")

print(f'Master:  {"".join(master)}')
hamming_distance(mutation)

Example output:

Master:  AATTATGTACCGGGAGCTCCG
Mutated: GTATCACGATGTCATCATCAA, 4, 0
Mutated: GGATCGGAAGACCACCCTCTG, 7, 1
Mutated: CTATCAGCAGAAGTTGCTCCG, 10, 2
Mutated: GCCTACGGAGTGGAAGCTCCG, 13, 3
Mutated: GCCTAGGCATGGGGAGCTCCG, 14, 4
Mutated: CTGTAGGAATCGGGAGCTCCG, 15, 5
Mutated: TGGTAAGCACCGGGAGCTCCG, 16, 6
Mutated: ATATATGTACCGGGAGCTCCG, 19, 7
Mutated: AGATATGTACCGGGAGCTCCG, 19, 8
Mutated: AACTATGTACCGGGAGCTCCG, 20, 9
Mutated: AACTATGTACCGGGAGCTCCG, 20, 10
Mutated: AAATATGTACCGGGAGCTCCG, 20, 11
Mutated: AATTATGTACCGGGAGCTCCG, 21, 12
Master sequence has been achieved
```

This accomplishes your first task and gets your desired output in the order of mutated sequence, hamming distance, and generation number. This finds all the positions of the point mutations in the mutation sequence. For each of those positions, it swaps it out with another random nucleotide. Using recursion, I was able to automatically evolve the mutation sequence. I added the condition so it would stop as soon as both sequences were equal. If you wanted to add another chance to the mutation, say a 1/10 chance you can do something like this before the part that actually swaps out each nucleotide.

```
    for num in list:
        i = random.randint(1, 10)
        if i == 5: # The 5 is a random number that I chose
            y = random.choice(nucleotides)
            mutation[num] = y
```

This is a very naive answer but it works well. Furthermore, I would make the sequences and random integer a user input to make the function more flexible.